# On MathJax-enabled sites preview and toolbar break completely when MathJax fails to load

Tags: feature-request, markdown-preview, mathjax, toolbar

[Recently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/133611/132564) I experienced some problem (I have no idea what it was) which caused the [MathJax](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MathJax) CDN to be unreachable from my network location.

Here's how "Ask Question" form looks like then:

[image]

You see, there's no toolbar, and no preview and no link to "upload image" control.

Meanwhile

1. I didn't even need MathJax to formulate the question - text with minimal [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) would be enough for me
2. some network resource becoming unreachable once in a while is ***just normal on the Internet*** - anything can happen in a distributed network.

The toolbar and preview should not break that harsh. They can degrade a bit, but they shouldn't break completely when MathJax fails to load.

Comment: Does this happen everywhere or just one SE site?  (Also, feature-request probably isn't the best tag for this, so I swapped with support and bug.)

Comment: @jmort253: I reproed that on Electronics SE, Math SE, Electronics SE Meta.

Comment: The missing toolbar is unrelated to MathJax.  Although MathJax failed to load, you also see 6 copies of the message "unexpected response code: 500" from electronics.stackexchange.com.  (The 500 error is an internal server error.)  Presumably these are the code and images needed to manage the toolbar.  The failure of MathJax to load is a second issue, but not the cause of the toolbar problem.

Answer (score 2):

This is apparently related to a problem with the CDN used to serve up the images for the toolbar, and this [the first time we've seen this problem](https://pm.meta.stackexchange.com/q/299/34) as there was a user on PMSE with the exact same symptoms. In his case, his firewall was blocking the CDN.

If something in your network configuration has recently changed, you may want to check the configuration. If you're accessing the network from the office, check with your IT department to see if they recently changed any firewall settings.

In addition, be sure to [try the steps listed here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92452/cdn-sstatic-net-is-slowing-down-initial-page-loads/100103#100103).

**UPDATE:** According to the [NetDNA Status Page](http://status.netdna.com/), there does appear to be an issue they expect to be resolved in 3 hours. Thus, this should hopefully go away on its own.

Comment: The question is requesting better fallback, not asking about the problem. I have reverted your tag edit because I believe it did not correctly characterize the intent of the asker.

Comment: @KevinReid - Very subtle, but I see that now. Thanks!